# Flash TextField, dynamic size

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, text, fonts

I'm building text balloons to display variable length messages in Flash. My question is pretty simple, though the answer may not be.

I have:

- The string I want to display.
- The font information.
- The width/height ratio I want the text field to have.

How do I calculate the width and height of the text field it needs to display the text I give it, nothing more, nothing less?

Comment: do you use a monospaced font? ;)

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but if you create a textfield object, than than set your text, can't you simply read the width of the textObject?
like:
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf.text = 'string to display';
trace (tf.width, tf.height)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest thing I can think off is creating a textfield, setting the custom font and text then getting the size:

e.g.

```
var field:TextField = new TextField();
field.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',12,0xDEDEDE);
field.text = 'someText';
trace(field.textWidth + ' / ' + field.textHeight);
```

[textWidth](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#textWidth) and [textHeight](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#textHeight) should give you the right numbers, as opposed the width and height properties. If you need more details than this, have a look at the [TextLineMetrics class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html).

HTH,
George

Comment: That would work. I need the text to span multiple lines, but I can calculate that. (TW / lines) / (TH * lines) = WHRATIO. Then field width = TW / lines

Comment: The solution: lines = sqrt((width/height)/ratio)

Answer (score 1):

if you turn on autoSize it should adjust the height of your text field for you. You can then just get the height using the same field.textHeight

```
var field:TextField = new TextField();
field.autoSize = "left";
field.multiline = true;
field.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',12,0xDEDEDE);
field.text = 'someText';
trace(field.textWidth + ' / ' + field.textHeight);
```

Comment: I thought about the same. But there is a difference between textWidth and the textField width. TextLineMetrics class that George Profenza pointed in his answer if really good to understand better this problem.

Comment: I am using autosize, but I still need to set the correct width to achieve a text field with the width/height ratio I want.